# Combining a parent table with multiple child tables

Tags: join, query

I am struggling to find a way to combine multiple tables (through a view) to get the desired result.

I've found [this Stack Overflow Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198124/combine-two-tables-that-have-no-common-fields), which got me startied, but I can't get the result I need.

There is a parent table and multiple child tables, which have a `child_id` that corresponds to a `parent_id`. However, each child has some matching fields and some unique  fields, which I'd like to combine all together.

#### Parent

```
+-----------+----------+
| parent_id | name     |
+-----------+----------+
|         1 | Bob      |
|         2 | Peter    |
|         3 | Alice    |
+-----------+----------+
```

#### Child 1

```
+----------+------------+-------+
| child_id | date       | color |
+----------+------------+-------+
|        1 | 2017-07-20 | red   |
|        3 | 2017-07-24 | blue  |
+----------+------------+-------+
```

#### Child 2

```
+----------+------------+--------+
| child_id | date       | lenght |
+----------+------------+--------+
|        2 | 2017-07-21 | 185    |
+----------+------------+--------+
```

#### Combined desired result

```
+-----------+-------+----------+------------+-------+--------+
| parent_id | name  | child_id | date       | color | lenght |
|         1 | Bob   |        1 | 2017-07-20 | red   | NULL   |
|         2 | Peter |        2 | 2017-07-21 | NULL  | 185    |
|         3 | Alice |        3 | 2017-07-24 | blue  | NULL   |
+-----------+-------+----------+------------+-------+--------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need outer joins. Specifically to `LEFT JOIN` the parent table with each child:

```
  parent
LEFT JOIN child1 AS c1 ON p.parent_id = c1.child_id
LEFT JOIN child2 AS c2 ON p.parent_id = c2.child_id
```

and then `SELECT` from the appropriate tables. Columns that are in both children tables can be combined with `COALESCE()`. The order of the expressions inside the function matter only if there are cases where an `id` appears in both childen.

The query will be something like:

```
SELECT 
    p.parent_id, p.name,
    COALESCE(c1.child_id, c2.child_id) AS child_id,
    COALESCE(c1.date, c2.date) AS date, 
    c1.color, 
    c2.lenght
FROM
    parent AS p
  LEFT JOIN child1 AS c1 ON p.parent_id = c1.child_id
  LEFT JOIN child2 AS c2 ON p.parent_id = c2.child_id ;
```